# pyspark TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, pyspark, recommendation-engine

I use spark 2.1.0.In the following code I load the rating data. Each row consists of a user, a product and a rating. I use the default `ALS.train()`method which assumes ratings are explicit,but it catch exception as follows:

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py", line 233, in <lambda>
        ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: Rating(*x))
    TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

In the docs, `pyspark.mllib.recommendation` module provide code as

```
 r1 = (1, 1, 1.0)
 r2 = (1, 2, 2.0)
 r3 = (2, 1, 2.0)
 ratings =sc.parallelize([r1, r2, r3])
 model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings,1, seed=10)
 model.predict(2, 2)
```

but it not work well when I change code,the error still.
The code as follow

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import Rating, ALS
  rawData = sc.textFile("/user/hadoop/ratings.dat")
  def gx(x):
     ratings=[]
     for item in x:
       q=item.split("::")
       ratings.append(Rating(int(q[0]),int(q[1]),float(q[2])))
      return ratings
  ratings = rawData.map(lambda l:gx(l))



model = ALS.train(ratings, 50, 10, 0.01)
```

How can I use `ALS.train` in pyspark.

Comment: Show the error given with the 'changed' code....

Comment: Only change the parameter eg:ALS.train(ratings,3,10,0.01)

Comment: But, what is the reported error?

Comment: Only change the parameter value. eg:ALS.train(ratings,3,10,0.01),If I invoke the ALS.trainImplicit(ratings,50,10,0.0.1) ,it work well, when execute  model.predict(789,123)  it report error . py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1191.predict.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator

Comment: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)